# Apply method within a django queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a Django queryset that returns all the staff called 'bob' working in all my restaurants. It does this successfully:

```
restaurant_staff = Restaurant.objects.filter(staff__staff_name="bob")
```

However, the Staff model has a method that returns only staff that were employed on a given date that I would like to use. Essentially I want all the bobs who are working on today. I've tried adding the method `.valid_on_certain_date(self, date.today())` onto the query but it uses the Restaurant classes `valid_on_certain_date` not the Staff class's `valid_on_certain_date` method:

```
restaurant_staff = Restaurant.objects.filter(staff__staff_name="bob").valid_on_certain_date(self, date.today())
```

A simplified version of my models.py:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    restaurant_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    restaurant_dates_open = DateRangeField()


class Staff(models.Model):
    staff_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
    employment_dates = DateRangeField()
```

My querysets.py:

```
class ValidityQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def valid_on_certain_date(self, date):
        return  self.filter(restaurant_dates_open__contains=date)
```

My question is, how can I filter the Staff class by `valid_on_certain_date` in the `Restaurant.objects.filter(staff__staff_name="bob")` query?

Comment: Why you are not simply querying `Restaurant.objects.filter(staff__staff_name="bob", staff__employee_dates__contains=date.today())` ?

Comment: Also if you want all restaurants where staff_name is Bob then you should have done it `Staff.objects.filter(staff_name="bob").select_related("restaurant")` This way you can add additional filter and your `valid_on_certain_date(date.today())` will also work.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. That makes sense. The problem is that I've got a little more complications in my actual code than my sample code above. I think the only way I can do it in my actual code is by using the method within Staff. Do you know if it is possible to do that within a Restaurant query?

Comment: If you start querying with Restuarant model then it will pick method from Restaurant class not from Staff class thatswhy you are not getting the right result.

Comment: Yes true but is there a way of doing the Staff query first and using its method there and then using the Restaurant query after? Like a two part query?

Comment: Yes this can be done

Comment: Ah amazing. Would you be able to give an example of this layout in the answers and I will accept :)

Comment: I've posted an answer with a few suggestions, but I'm pretty sure your code is _very_ different from what you posted, because that seems to me completely non-operational. It would be amazing to have a more concrete code to give you the best suggestion. There are many ways to do this that have slight differences.

Comment: The main problem with your question is the `valid_on_certain_date`. There are 2 main types concerning the models. One is the model itself - `Restaurant` and `Staff`, the other is the representation of the query you're about to send - a `QuerySet`. Filtering is something you do on the qs, not the model, so your `valid_on_certain_date` method won't be accessible this way - `Staff.objects.all().valid_on_certain_date`

Comment: Sorry Jura, you're absolutely correct about the location of the queryset method. I've just updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: No worries. There's one more thing. This query:
`restaurant_staff = Restaurant.objects.filter(staff__staff_name="bob")`

It doesn't return staff working in your restaurants. It returns restaurants which have staff with name 'bob'

Comment: And I've changed my answer slightly to reflect the change too :)

Comment: Why are you extending `Queryset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you won't ever get a `StaffQuerySet` from the `Restaurant` model. You can at best get the ids of the staff by using `restaurant_qs.values_list('staff__id', flat=True)`.

To get a qs of `Staff`, you'll have to first get the restaurant ids and then call the `Staff` model:

```
restaurant_ids = Restaurant.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)  # filter the restaurants more here
staff = Staff.objects.filter(
    staff_name='bob',
    restaurant__id__in=your_restaurant_ids
).valid_on_certain_date(date)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because `filter()` returns a `Queryset` which doesn't have `valid_on_certain_date()` method.

Comment: The question was edited, the QuerySet Tomas uses is custom and has that method.

Comment: Does `Staff.object.filter()` return an instance of that custom queryset without some additional work?

Comment: Tomas forgot to add here the line that tells the Staff model to use his custom QuerySet, but yes. Check managers here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/

Comment: ok that makes sense. I gave a link about managers in my answer. I had in mind implementing the filter directly in a custom manager method without a queryset subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Extending `Queryset` won't work by itself because Django doesn't know about your custom subclass. I think what you need is a custom [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/). You probably don't need the `Queryset` subclass at all.